# date validator that cannot choose old date and today date in c#

Tags: asp.net, validation

When user insert the selected date in the textbox the date cannot be an old date or today date what is validation rule i can use?

i am not sure which validator control to use either.

Comment: Do you realy need it in a `Validation` control? Using code-behind for this is quite simple.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your aspx markup, that'll help us to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

For this non-standard case, you'll need to use a `CustomValidator`, which will require you to write a server-side validation function. MSDN has details here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

One way is using a `CustomValidator` with a `ServerValidate` like this:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server"
    ID="CustDateValidator" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDate"
    onservervalidate="CustDateValidator_ServerValidate" 
    ErrorMessage="enter valid date in the future" />
```

Code-behind:

```
protected void CustDateValidator_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime dt;
    args.IsValid = (DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, out dt) 
                    && dt > DateTime.Today);
}
```

You can also provide a [`ClientValidationFunction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.clientvalidationfunction.aspx)if you want(implementation is up to you).

**Note**: If the input control is empty, no validation functions are called and validation succeeds.

If you need to ensure that it's not empty then you'll need a `RequiredFieldValidator` too.

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg: So what have you tried and what (new) error do you get or which undesired result? Show your aspx in your question. Please avoid phrases like _"doesn't work"_ since it's not informative at all.

Comment: Tim the aspx is same as what you have put up, the undesired result is that the date i chose can be past date which is not what i want

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg: But since you haven't shown your aspx, i have provided an example which - of course - doesn't work if your control is not `txtDate` for example. Is the serverside validation function hit at all? Use the debugger and set a breakpoint there (also in `Page_Load`).

Comment: Hi i realized the DateTime dt; value =01-jan-2001 12:00 AM

Comment: I don't understand your last comment.

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg: The value is `DateTime.MinValue` what is `00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001`. You see that value because your breakpoint is at the beginning of the event handler. Skip after the `args.IsValid` line and shou should see the correctly initialized `DateTime` variable (if the string could be parsed to DateTime successfully). Anyway, apparently the custom validator works as expected.

Comment: tim but why am i still able to select a old date?

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg: Have you looked if `args.IsValid = false`? You can _select_ wrong dates, but the validator fires when the user clicks a submit button (or you have set `AutoPostBack="true"` on the textbox).

Comment: checked args.IsValid = false , my textbox is autopostback

Comment: @MalcolmNathanielNg: So does the validator show the error-message after the user entered/selected a date in the past? Maybe the problem is somewhere else and you have code in `Page_Load` that does not belong there (or should be wrapped in `if(!IsPostBack)`-check) and causes that behaviour.  Please mention again the problem, should the user not be able to _select_ a wrong date or should the user be informed that he _selected_ a wrong date after he tried to submit?

Comment: a recap, when user select a wrong date no error message is shown, btw my textbox has a calender extender for user to select dates