# range validator not working in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, rangevalidator

I have a date that I'm trying to validate in my web form...

here is the validator I'm using but it doesn't seem to work...

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="rgBHPECoOcuuring" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Assessment Date must be greater than the Birth Date of the Patient and not in the future"
 ValidationGroup="save" ControlToValidate="dtAssessmentDate" Display="None" >
</asp:RangeValidator>
```

So what I do is I display a DOB in lbDOB - what I'm hoping to do is make sure that date is not in the future, and has to be at least greater than Birth Date

Any ideas?

Comment: You are missing the `Type`, `MinimumValue` and `MaximumValue`. How is a range validator going to validate without a range.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to use a custom validator here and implement the onservervalidate handler.

[CustomValidator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355604/date-validator-that-cannot-choose-old-date-and-today-date-in-c-sharp)